# jQuery - delay if/else processing until ".get" call is completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a piece of code set up to check a condition, and based on that condition, either execute an ajax call to get a JSON object, or proceed to another form of processing.  After the processing, I then do some stuff based on the data processed in the if/else statement.

I'm running into a problem, however.  The code executes the if/else, and then continues on before the .get is finished processing, and thus my last bit of code doesn't work properly.  Is there a way to delay the processing of the rest of the code until the .get is completed?

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
if(filename != undefined){
  $.get(filename, function(json){
    $.each(json, function(data){
      // Do stuff with the json
    });
  }, "json");
} else {
  // Do some other processing
}

// Do some additional processing based on the results from the if/else statement
// This bit is getting processed before the .get has finished doing it's thing
// Therefore there isn't anything for it to act upon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `async: false` option for `$.get` to make synchronous requests. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**NOTE:**

> @Neal: "this is not always the best option. especially if the ajax request hangs for too long."

Comment: @Kevin -- this is not always the best option. especially if the ajax request hangs for too long.

Comment: Thx Neal, that's true. I'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Make a callback function instead for the rest of the operation:

```
if(filename != undefined){
  $.get(filename, function(json){
    $.each(json, function(data){
      // Do stuff with the json
      doTheRest();
    });
  }, "json");
} else {
  // Do some other processing
  doTheRest();
}

function doTheRest(){

   // Do some additional processing based on the results from the if/else statement

}
```

Just remember variable scopes, and if you have to, pass parameters into the `doTheRest` function.